# Plupload 2 does not give error when it should

Tags: plupload

I'm using plupload to upload some files using AJAX. Under "Create upload handler" in the [Plupload Documentation](http://www.plupload.com/docs/Getting-Started) it states that you can return `{"OK": 0}` in cause of an error.

I am trying to get this to work. I would like to throw an error when the server rejects the upload. I have my code throwing `{"OK": 0}` immediately, and it is working. Here is the network response (edit.php):

[image]

With this, Plupload is still firing the `FileUploaded` event and is NOT firing the `Error` event. I also do not see any way to access the returned JSON string (aka, the value of "OK") inside the FileUploaded event.

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({ ... });
uploader.init();

// When a file has been uploaded
uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file) {
  log('FileUploaded', up, file);
});

// Display errors if they occurr
uploader.bind('Error', function(up, err) {
  log('Error', up, err);
});
```

Here is the result, notice the event text is "FileUploaded" instead of "Error".

[image]

How do I make `"OK":0` fire the error event - or at least not act like the upload was successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return HTTP status 500 from the server.

See also [this thread](http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=1804).

Comment: Ah good idea. Not sure why my google search didn't come up with that thread. I should have checked their forums, I suppose. The documentation is pretty bad, they never mention a third parameter for the FilesUploaded event. Thanks!